# How to copy a given column of several textx files into a csv, each column from each file in one csv column

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv

I'm quite an amateur regarding python and I'm stuck.

So I managed to write a script to extract the second column of floats of a list of text files, from the line 5025 to the end, and create a list containing all these columns to export them into a csv.

My problem is that in the csv, all the columns from each file are pasted in one single column in the csv. So, what I wanted is that each column of each file in my list to be pasted in a different column of the csv (if I have 4 files to process, I would like to have 4 columns in the csv, one per file).

So here is what I have now:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import numpy as np

def read_csv(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines[5025:len(lines)] #ignoring 5025 first lines

def extract_second_column(file_path): #returns second column
    lines = read_csv(file_path)
    second_col = []
    for elem in lines:
        elem = elem.split()
        second_col.append(float(elem[1]))
    return second_col

def combined_array(file_path_list): #combines all columns to one array
    all_values = []
    for file_path in file_path_list:
        col_data = extract_second_column(file_path)
        all_values.append(col_data)
    return all_values

def write_csv(data, csv_name ):  #writes the array to a csv file
    
    np.savetxt(csv_name, data, delimiter="\n")
        
#Now the magic happens:

file_name_list = ["GLN-46_Coul.xvg","GLN-46_LJ.xvg","GLU-102_Coul.xvg","GLU-102_LJ.xvg"]

data = combined_array(file_name_list)   #array containing all columns

write_csv(data, "ENERGIES.csv") #writing to csv file
```

I will appreciate whatever suggestion! I'm aware that the code looks ugly but what I need right now is something that works.

Comment: you are appending all data to the all_values list. That's why everything is on one column

Comment: try this def combined_array(file_path_list): #combines all columns to one array
    all_values = []
    for file_path in file_path_list:
        col_data = extract_second_column(file_path)
        all_values.append(col_data)
    rows = zip(all_values)
    return rows
    
data = combined_array(file_name_list)   #array containing all columns
    
with open(newfilePath, "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)